# How do I tell Shopify's Themekit to ignore .svn files?

Tags: shopify

I am editing a Shopify Theme on my desktop, and using Themekit's `theme watch` to upload changes to Shopify. I am using Subversion, which creates .svn directories. How do I prevent Themekit from trying to upload these .svn directories to Shopify?

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry like this to your theme's `config.yml` file:

```
  ignore_files:
  - "*.svn*"
```

For this to take effect, stop `theme watch` and then run it again.